# Automatic logout after every some screen unlock - 18.04 - Wayland

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, wayland

At first I though it's a problem with suspend. I found issues about it, tried some fixes, even upgraded Kernel to the latest version... the problem still persisted.

After that I though it's connected with Spotify as I saw some of its segfaults in `dmesg`.
I stopped using it, but the problem persisted.

Later I though it may be connected with Electron, but even without any Electron app launched I started to keep locking my screen and unlocking ended up with discovery that every some time I lock my screen and unlock it, the logout follows.

Only other hint I found is the following kind of error in `dmesg`.

```
gnome-shell[12710]: segfault at 14af00000014 ip 00007f76be14cf51 sp 00007fff4cd00908 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.3[7f76be117000+52000]
```

I'm not sure though if it appears every time or not. I tried to search for it, even found some issues, but they didn't seem connected with this issue.

I also tried removing `vino` as - as far as I believe - it bases on XServer, but it didn't help.

I have only integrated graphics card and no other video drivers installed than default ones.

I just wonder - what causes such behavior? Is it just a Wayland bug?

Comment: @user68186, where would You report it then? I'm not really sure what causes that.

Comment: @user68186, ok, thanks, no worries. I'm just a bit skeptical about it, as it seems very generic to me. And, after all, I think I've found a source of that problem and a solution. Thank You again though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a source of that behavior. I seems connected to **Gnome Extensions** and I even managed to narrow it down. I think it's caused by **Time++** extension and maybe some other ones I have also disabled. To be honest, at least some of Time++ features seemed to work well even on Wayland, but maybe some others require XServer and change to Wayland started causing problems.

The lesson from that: when You experience any weird behavior of Gnome Shell **start from disabling all extensions**. Than, if it doesn't help, look for other possible sources of problem.